# Fileserver returns 404 for all files

Tags: go, webserver, http-status-code-404, fileserver

So whenever I try to access any files in my static sub-directory, I just get a 404, Not Found, Accessing Home/ on the other hand works just fine, but a picture that I call from the home file is simply broken :(, So I'd like to know what to change so that I can serve files and redirect my root directory at the same time.

My Path structure:

```
root/
->html
->static
->entry.go
```

I saw the other threads on here, they all recommend that I do r.PathPrefix("/").Handler(...), but doing that makes it so accessing any file outside static returns NIL, including my html files which are in a separate html file in the root of my project, furthermore, redirecting to any of them returns 404, Not Found.

Here's the code:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "net/http"
  "html/template"
  "github.com/gorilla/mux"
  "os"
)

func IfError(err error, quit bool) {
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    if(quit) {
      os.Exit(1);
    }
  }
}

func NotFound(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  w.WriteHeader(404)
  t, _ := template.ParseFiles("html/404")
  err := t.Execute(w, nil)
  IfError(err, false)
}

func Home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  t, _ := template.ParseFiles("html/home")
  err := t.Execute(w, nil)
  IfError(err, false)
}

func RedirectRoot(servefile http.Handler) http.Handler {
  return http.HandlerFunc(func (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.URL.Path == "/" {
      redirect := r.URL.Host+"/home"
      http.Redirect(w, r, redirect, http.StatusSeeOther)
    } else {
      servefile.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }
  })
}

func main()  {
  r := mux.NewRouter()
  ServeFiles := http.StripPrefix("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static/")))
  r.Handle("/", RedirectRoot(ServeFiles))
  r.HandleFunc("/home", Home)
  r.NotFoundHandler = http.HandlerFunc(NotFound)

  fmt.Printf("Listening ...")
  IfError(http.ListenAndServe(":8081", r), true)
}
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I see in your code

```
r.Handle("/", RedirectRoot(ServeFiles))
```

It will match every route, may produce unexpected results. Instead map your routes clearly and explicitly then it will work as you expect.

**For eg.:** Let's maps the handler with responsibility. This approach based on your directory structure.

It will only expose `static` directory via file server, remaining files and root directory is safe.

```
func main()  {
   r := mux.NewRouter()
   r.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/",    http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))))
   r.HandleFunc("/home", Home)
   r.NotFoundHandler = http.HandlerFunc(NotFound)

   fmt.Printf("Listening ...")
   IfError(http.ListenAndServe(":8081", r), true)
}
```

`RedirectRoot` may not be needed for your purpose.

Now, `/static/*` served by `http.FileServer` and `/home` handled by `Home`.

---

**EDIT:**

As asked in the comment. To map root `/` to home handler and `/favicon.ico`, add following in-addition to above code snippet.

```
func favIcon(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "static/favicon.ico")
} 

r.HandleFunc("/favicon.ico", favIcon)
r.HandleFunc("/", Home)
```

`favicon.ico` served from `static` directory.

Comment: But I want my root directory to redirect to home/, accessing the website with your imlementation will give me a 404, Not found, and the favicon.ico will not be loaded either

Comment: Added further details to the answer, please have a look.